# Access latest state value in the same function that is used to set the state

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

my state

```
const [selectedRows, setSelected] = useState([])

const handleRowClick = useCallback((id) => {
       if(selectedRows.includes[id]) {
           arr = selectedRows.filter((item) => item !== id) // <==Trying to access the state here
           setSelected((prev) => [arr])
       } else {
          setSelected((prev) => [id])
       }    
})
```

Everytime I try to access the selectedRows inside the handleRowClick function it just returns its default value,ie. an empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't using a dependency array for `useCallback`. You probably want this:

```
const handleRowClick = useCallback((id) => {
       if(selectedRows.includes[id]) {
           arr = selectedRows.filter((item) => item !== id) // <==Trying to access the state here
           setSelected((prev) => [...arr])
       } else {
          setSelected((prev) => [...id])
       }    
}, [selectedRows])
```

Note: notice that I'm destructuring the array so you get a new copy of the array and not an array with just one element.